# Facebook: Is it possible to DELETE a Checkin via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

When I post a checkin to Facebook the API returns the id of the story created.

How can I delete this story?

I tried to delete using

```
DELETE -> /me/ID
```

or

```
DELETE -> /ID
```

without success.
I received the response `GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.`

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible via the API. From the documentation, it says - `"NOTE: Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating a Post with a location attached."`. I  know for sure that you can delete posts created by your application, perhaps that is a better way to proceed..

Comment: In addition, you really should mention what you mean by `"without success"`. Did you see an error message of some sort? What exactly went wrong?

Comment: Never saw this Deprecation Warning from the docs... Do you know when they started changing this behavior?

Comment: I don't think you were ever allowed to delete a checkin. I don't think this is something new. You can however follow changes in the [developers road map](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't work for me either:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported delete request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

But, as Lix quoted:

> NOTE: Publishing a Checkin object is **deprecated** in favor of creating a [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) with a location attached.

*From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/*

It means that `Checkin` should not be used anymore. Instead, you have to create a `Post`.

> You can create a post on behalf of the user by issuing an HTTP POST
>   request to PROFILE_ID/feed (not PROFILE_ID/posts)

**Creating a post with a location:**

[image: Let's check in at New York!]

Result:

```
{
  "id": "1022369832_4517701013579"
}
```

**Deleting the post with a location:**

```
DELETE -> http://graph.facebook.com/1022369832_4517701013579
```

Result: `true`

I think that you haven't any other choice.