# Checkin using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to checkin, the part from the PHP code:

```
$attachment =  array('access_token' => '$access',                        
                     'place'        => '117464364938130',
                     'message'      => 'I am place to check in',
                     'coordinates'  => array(
                              'latitude'  => '40',
                              'longitude' => '-73',)
                    );
```

but I get error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#160) Invalid coordinates. Coordinates must contain at least latitude, and longitude.","type":"OAuthException","code":160}}
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the coordinates as JSON

```
$attachment =  array('access_token'  => '$access',                        
                     'place'          => '117464364938130',
                     'message' => 'I am place to check in',
                     'coordinates' => json_encode(array(
                                        'latitude'  => '40',
                                        'longitude' => '-73')))
```

Comment: I get the same error: "{"error":{"message":"(#160) Invalid coordinates. Coordinates must contain at least latitude, and longitude.","type":"OAuthException","code":160}}"

Comment: What if you try 40.0, -73.0 ? also try as numbers, without ''

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$attachment =  array('access_token' => '$access',                        
                     'place' => '117464364938130',
                     'message' => 'I am place to check in',
                     'coordinates' => '{"latitude": 40, "longitude": -73}');
```

By the way, you shouldn't use the `Checkin` object anymore or you might meet some more problems. Instead, use `Post`. Moreover, you won't need to specify the coordinates, which will solve your problem anyway! Please also read my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821460/facebook-is-it-possible-to-delete-a-checkin-via-graph-api/13828245#13828245).